# Connect Wear os watch to android studio with an iPhone

Tags: android

I have a fossil smart watch and have been messing around with wear os apps lately and was wondering if there is a way to connect my watch to android studio. I have seen guides online about doing this but they are all for android so I was wondering if it is possible with IOS or some other method.

Comment: Wear OS is (AFAIK) based on Android, so it should be possible to connect your device to android studio. Have a look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise ADB worked over WI-FI